# JavaScript - Array behaves like object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'd like to ask a question about JavaScript arrays.
Does the array behave like an object when we use for..in loop to iterate. I mean in this case can indexes take the role of properties(keys).

Comment: No, it doesn't. Don't use `for..in` to iterate arrays.

Comment: Yes, indexes are keys, but you shouldn’t use `for..in` to loop over them; if you do that, the order of iteration isn’t guaranteed, and you could get other enumerable properties.

Comment: If you want `foreach` semantics in javascript, look at `Array.prototype.forEach`. You can basically do this: `[0, 1, 2, 3].forEach(function(item, key) { /* do stuff with item and key */ });`. Though you can't `break` and `continue` it.

Comment: I have used JSON to wrap an object into an array.  But, like others' comment, it is not guaranteed for the result you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Alxandr: `forEach`, isn’t it?

Comment: @minitech Ah, yes. You're right. Fixed. Thanks for the heads up though :)

Answer (score 0):

While you can do for..in syntax on an array, you shouldn't because you will will iterate over any properties you may have assigned to the array.

```
Example:
var array = [0, 1];
array.three = 2;
for (var p in array){
    console.log(array[p]); //print 0, 1, 2
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i]); //prints 0, 1
}
```

So, when dealing with arrays you should always use the for var i approach to avoid running into unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As everything in JS, an array is an object.

It means you can use an array as a prototype :

```
var obj = Object.create([]);
console.log(obj instanceof Array); // true
obj[0] = "value 1";
obj.test = "value of property test";
for(var i in obj) console.log(obj[i]); // "value 1" "value of property test"
```

or any other thing you would do with an object, including using a `for ... in` loop.

However, the `length` property is updated with the highest (integer) index of the array +1.

```
var arr = ["one","two"];
arr.length; // 2
```

That's why it's preferred not to use `for ... in` loops when you only want to iterate on the values of the array : you can use `for(var i=0,var l=arr.length;i<arr.length;i++)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Yes ,you can access array like an object Only if array **keys** are **string**,

```
var sdf = [];
sdf['asd'] =45;
sdf[32] =8674;

console.log(sdf.asd)  // WORKS
console.log(sdf.32)  // Error
```

Comment: In this case `asd` isn't an array key though. It's just an added property. Also, does not answer question.

Comment: That’s not a feature of arrays. `var sdf = {}; sdf[32] = 8674; console.log(sdf[32]);`

Answer (score -1):

Array.prototype.forEach is what you want. Just be mindful of browser support or use a framework that corrects for unsupported browsers: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.forEach

for in should be used for iterating over object properties because order is not guaranteed.